# Lista con clave foranea para llenar combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

quisiera ver si me pueden dar su ayuda (les estaré muy agradecido).

tengo un ComboBox que lo lleno desde una lista de datos obtenida de una BD en MySql,

El codigo de la lista es este;

```
    public List<Libro> listaLibros()
    {
        List<Libro> lista = new List<Libro>();

        String consulta = "SELECT IdLibro, ISBN, Titulo, Editorial, Paginas, Autores_idAutor FROM libros";
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, this.cn);
        adaptador.Fill(this.tabla);


        foreach (DataRow fila in this.tabla.Rows)
        {
            Libro autFill = new Libro(fila[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(fila[1]), fila[2].ToString(), fila[3].ToString(), fila[4].ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(fila[5]));
            lista.Add(autFill);
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

al llenar el autFill en la fila[5] tengo el problema, puesto que en la BD, dicho campo es una clave de otra tabla, por lo cual en vez de llenar así hago un cast de esta manera:

```
        foreach (DataRow fila in this.tabla.Rows)
        {
            Libro autFill = new Libro(fila[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(fila[1]), fila[2].ToString(), fila[3].ToString(), fila[4].ToString(), (Autor) fila[5]);
            lista.Add(autFill);
        }
```

Ahí no me  marca error el compilador, pero al correr el programa se cae, el error que me arroja es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe considerar que Autor es una clase.

Les estaría agradecido de antemano.

Comment: Claro. No puedes hacer un cast de un id que es un int a una clase. Si Autor es una clase, tendrías que tener un método en esa clase que cargue el autor dado un id en concreto, y pasar eso al constructor de Libro

Comment: Lo que tenes que hacer, es, relacionar las tablas con tu llave foránea, así obtener la información relevante a `autor`, poder crear una instancia de `autor` y recién ahí tendrías tu parámetro

Comment: Les agradecería me pudieran dar un ejemplo tanto del metodo que me propones, como de la manera de relacionar ambas tablas. Por favor.

Comment: Lo que pedís es algo muy amplio, que se va un poco de las normas de StackOverflow, te recomiendo que leas acerca de los [**Join**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) que te va a orientar un poco más acerca de como resolver tu problema.. de ahí, cuando tengas alguna duda puntual, va a ser muy bien recibida y seguramente contestada aquí!